# bootstrap empty space after css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really really hope somebody can help me with this problem, because I am stuck in my project before I find a solution.

If you look at the picture there as an empty space after the blue test col in the right hand side. I cannot understand why it is there? I would like that the blue col is going all the way out to the edge of the page.

When I remove the code in my throws.css it is working fine, which means that the blue test col is going all the way out to the right side.

Can somebody help me with this, so I can get on with my project.

[image: Layout]

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper bg-info">
            <div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 bg-danger">
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                        <h4>Home</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1" id="throw_1">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 bg-success" id="content">
                         Content
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="throw_2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-success" id="throw_3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="throw_4">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-info col-height col-bottom">
                       test test test test test test test test test
                    </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

CSS throws.css

```
#throw_1 {

  height: 500px;
  width: 65px;
  border: 2px solid #FFECB3;
  margin: 5px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#throw_2 { 
  height: 330px;
  width: 65px;
  font-size: 13px;
   margin: 5px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fe5606 0%, #fd9a00 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}

#throw_3 {
  height: 330px;
  width: 65px;
    margin: 5px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a4ed5 0%, #3acfd5 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}

#throw_4 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 65px;
  border: 2px solid #FFECB3;
  margin: 5px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

/* black sidebar in left side of the screen*/

sidebar.css

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

    .sidebar-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 250px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li {
        text-indent: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:active,
    .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
        height: 65px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 60px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
        color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: none;
    }

    @media(min-width:768px) {
        #wrapper {
            padding-left: 150px;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled {
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        #sidebar-wrapper {
            width: 150px;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
            width: 0;
        }

        #page-content-wrapper {
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello LPK. Is it the following the code you mean i shoudl change?
<div id="page-content-wrapper bg-info">
            <div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 bg-danger">

The sidebar is this one: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/ and is in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `width` to your `#throw` divs. When you apply `specific` width to Bootstrap column classes it will not work as `col-lg-1` it suppose to be.

Here is your fixed code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shortcuts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper bg-info">
        <div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 bg-danger">
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    <h4>Home</h4>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1" id="throw_1">
                      <div class="fixed-width-col red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 bg-success" id="content">Content</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="throw_2">
                      <div class="fixed-width-col blue"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-success" id="throw_3">
                      <div class="fixed-width-col green"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="throw_4">
                      <div class="fixed-width-col yellow"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-info col-height col-bottom">test test test test test test test test test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

sidebar.css: unchanged

throws.css

```
.fixed-width-col{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #Fefefe;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.red{
  border: 2px solid #f22125;
}
.blue{
  border: 2px solid #3179be;
}
.green{
  border: 2px solid #abd03b;
}
.yellow{
  border: 2px solid #f8ee4c;
}
#throw_1 {
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #FFECB3;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#throw_2 { 
  height: 330px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fe5606 0%, #fd9a00 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#throw_3 {
  height: 330px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a4ed5 0%, #3acfd5 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#throw_4 {
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #FFECB3;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/038agxe6/4/

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. But if I am not setting a width on my <div throw_1> they will not stay the same size? It is very important for me(if it is possible, that they stay the same size). Can I wrap in a new div instead fx?

Comment: They will remain same `width` unless you change the class `col-lg-1`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/038agxe6/1/ not sure if this is what you mean for wrap in a new div. Here I have added 65px fixed width within each column.

Comment: Hello everybody. Thank you so much. I just got back from work and tried the code. It is actually working, but the fixed code in css is not working. Do you have any idea of what that could be?

Comment: Hey, Glad to help you out. Just add the border to `.fixed-width-col` . Just updated the code. https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/038agxe6/2/

Comment: It is actually working now. On your code you make the white div tag, the white line there is 65px width; How can I set a border on that one? When I make borders now, they are going on the bootstrap col, which means that the borders are flying out from the white line on 65px; I can of course set it on the .fixed-width-col with a border: 1px solid black; But two of my boxes has to have a specifik color. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: You can apply each of them a different class name and apply border to each one. https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/038agxe6/4/

Comment: But where the shoot are you calling those class name from the html? edit: I see now. I do not have to put anything in the empty div tag, where you call <div class="fixed-width-col red"></div> it just have to be empty?

Comment: Thank you so very much. Everything is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are giving manual **width** for #throw_1,2,3 etc., It should be converted to **percentage** to occupy the entire screen.

Or in other words, just remove the **width's** from throws.css for each column. You already have col-lg-1, etc., let bootstrap handle the width.

Comment: If I add a % for my <div throw_1> etc, will they stay the same size, so they are not getting bigger and so on? So never use width 100 px;, when I use bootstrap? Is it the same princible for the height? I have to let the content to deside the height of a col?

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep your design responsive avoid giving width. Although you can give height. The div's will be automatically adjust based on the percentage/ grid class provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Start Bootstrap
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper bg-info">
        <div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 bg-danger">
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    <h4>Home</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row padding-zero">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <div id="throw_1"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7 bg-success">
                <div id="content"></div>
                     Content
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="">
                <div id="throw_2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 bg-success" id="">
                    <div id="throw_3"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning" id="">
                    <div id="throw_4"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 bg-info col-height col-bottom">
                   test test test test test test test test test
                </div>
            </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

#throw_1 {
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #FFECB3;
  margin: 5px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#throw_2 { 
  height: 330px;

  font-size: 13px;
   margin: 5px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fe5606 0%, #fd9a00 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}

#throw_3 {
  height: 330px;

    margin: 5px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a4ed5 0%, #3acfd5 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}

#throw_4 {
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #FFECB3;
  margin: 5px;
  background-image:url("../img/boardbg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-size: 13px;
}



#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

    .sidebar-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 250px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li {
        text-indent: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:active,
    .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
        height: 65px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 60px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
        color: #999999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: none;
    }

    @media(min-width:768px) {
        #wrapper {
            padding-left: 150px;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled {
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        #sidebar-wrapper {
            width: 150px;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
            width: 0;
        }

        #page-content-wrapper {
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }
    .padding-zero > div{
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

Please remove the width and margin from the div. I have done few changes in html as well as css please check.